# Пропускает ввод строки в Java

Tags: java, строки, input, ввод

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program    {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int c = 0;

        System.out.print("Input number 1: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input Name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Input number 2: ");
        int b = in.nextInt();


    }
}
```

Код запускается но после ввода номера 1, он пропускает имя и сразу просит ввести номер 2.
Вот это вводит:

```
Input number 1: 5
Input Name: Input number 2:
```

Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Исправленный вариант:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = 0;

    System.out.print("Input number 1: ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input Name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input number 2: ");
    int b = in.nextInt();
```

У вас при считывании переменной **а** вы после того как вводите число и жмете Enter передаете кроме самого числа и символ перевода каретки "\n", он и записывается в "name". Строка кода

```
 in.nextLine();
```

"съедает" лишний символ перевода каретки и программа работает правильно

Comment: Благодарю за помощь